# Need to close a modal on state exit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using UI-Router and angular bootstrap-ui. I have a state setup to create modal 'onEnter'. I'm having problems now when I'm trying to close the modal 'onExit'. Here is the basic state. It will open a modal when 'items.detail' is entered and it will transitions to 'items' when that modal is closed or dismissed.

```
.state('items.detail', {
    url: '/{id}',
    onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/modal/item-detail.html',
            controller: 'itemDetailCtrl'
        })
        .result.then(function () {
            $state.transitionTo('items');
        }, function () {
            $state.transitionTo('items');
        });
    }
})
```

I've tried using the onExit handler like so. But haven't been able to access the modalInstance or the scope that the modal is in from that handler. Everything I try to inject comes up undefined.

```
.state('items.detail', {
    url: '/{id}',
    onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/modal/item-detail.html',
            controller: 'itemDetailCtrl'
        })
        .result.then(function () {
            $state.transitionTo('items');
        }, function () {
            $state.transitionTo('items');
        });
    },
    onExit: function ($scope) {
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $modal) {
            $modalInstance.dismiss();
        };
    }
})
```

from within my modal's controller I've tried listening for state changes.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss();
});
```

I've tried this with both $scope.$on and $rootScope.$on and both of these work but they end up being called every time I transition between any states. This only happens however after I've opened the modal.

In case this last bit is unclear... When I refresh my angular app I can transition between all my other states with out this listener event being called but after I open that modal all of my state changes get called by that listener, even after the modal is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can better organize your modal opening behavior.I would not use onEnter and onExit handlers inside state definition. Instead it's better to define controller which should handle modal:

```
.state('items.detail', {
    url: '/{id}',
    controller:'ItemDetailsController',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
})
```

Then define your controller:

```
.controller('ItemDetailsController', [
    function($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/modal/item-detail.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                itemId: function () {
                   return $stateParams.id;
            }
         modalInstance.result.then(function () {
                $state.go('items');
            }, function () {
                $state.go('items');
         });
      }
    });       
    }
])
```

Then define your ModalInstanceCtrl:

```
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', [ 
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, itemId) {

        //Find your item from somewhere using itemId and some services
        //and do your stuff


        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close('ok');
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
           $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    };
]);
```

In this way you modal will be closed within ModalInstanceCtrl, and you will not worry about state's onExit handler.

About listener added on $scope. Seems when you add the listener and never remove it whenever your state changes, this is causing memory leak and handler function gets executed every time your app changes his state! So it's better to get rid of that event listener as you don't need it actually.

Comment: Thank you this seems to be a much better solution, and was easy to implement.

Comment: Wait I think in the heat of the moment I misunderstood what was happening. Now that I'm home from work it's not closing the modal on state changes, Im guessing it never was or I changed something. Anyways what part of this would close the modal when the state is left?

Comment: call to the $state.go('items') changes your state, but your modal instance should be closed before state change, when you call close or dismiss on $modalInstance within ModalInstanceCtrl

Comment: Those cases do work. The cases that I"m trying to catch are if the user hits the back button while the modal is open or modifies the url. In these cases it will enter a new state while leaving the modal open.

Comment: I think I'm over engineering this solution. I think what makes sense is to simply have a nested state that looks like a modal and doesn't call a ui-bootstrap modal. This will interact as desired with state transitions and I can easily create a background click to navigate to the parent state.

Comment: But `onEnter` is what is recommended in the ui-router docs, specifically addressing the question "How do I tell ui-router that I'd like a certain state to open a dialog or modal instead of swapping out ui-view templates?".

Answer (score 7):

Although the question is quite old, as I ran into the same situation recently, and came up with a better solution, I decided to share my results here anyway. The key point is to move the $modal.open service into resolve part of the state, which is kind of pre-load data and $promise services, and then inject the resolved modelInstance into onEnter, onExit etc. Codes might looks like as follow:

```
.state('items.detail', {
    url: '/{id}',
    resolve: {
        modalInstance: function(){
            return $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'views/modal/item-detail.html',
                controller: 'itemDetailCtrl'
            })
        },
    },
    onEnter: function ($stateParams, $state, modalInstance, $resource) {
        modalInstance 
        .result.then(function () {
            $state.transitionTo('items');
        }, function () {
            $state.transitionTo('items');
        });
    },
    onExit: function (modalInstance) {
        if (modalInstance) {
            modalInstance.close();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer. It accomplishes exactly what author wanted

Comment: For anyone wanting to see this work with ui-router's $previousState, simply record the previous state in onEnter like so: `onEnter: function($previousState) { $previousState.memo('modalInvoker'); }` - no other changes are needed. You can then use a button or whatever to return to that state as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent leaving the state by listening for the [`$stateChangeStart` event](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    console.log('$stateChangeStart', toState);
    if (toState.name != 'items.list'){
        event.preventDefault();
        var top = $modalStack.getTop();
        if (top) {
            $modalStack.dismiss(top.key);
        }
        $state.go('items.list');
    }
});
```

Comment: All these events are fired at the $rootScope level. [cit.]